# How do I check and alert for duplicates being inserted into my table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

For each make and model added via the "add" button, I need to check for a duplicate, set an alert if there is a duplicate and not let it add to the table. Cannot seem to find the solution...

Below is the entire code for the beginner project I am working on. My apologies ahead of time for this post, it is my first here... Thanks all.

```
<div>
 <div>Make: <input type="text" ng-model="make"></div>
 <div>Model:<input type="text" ng-model="model"></div>
 <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
```

```
    <tr>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-click="rowClick(car)">
        <td>{{car.make}}</td>
        <td>{{car.model}}</td>
    </tr>
```

```
  <table class="table carsTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-click="rowClick(car)">
        <td>{{car.make}}</td>
        <td>{{car.model}}</td>
    </tr>
```

```
<script>
var carsApp = angular.module('carsApp', []);



carsApp.controller('carController', function ($scope){

   $scope.cars = [];

  $scope.add = function () {



    $scope.cars.push({
       make: $scope.make,
       model: $scope.model

    });

    $scope.make = null;
    $scope.model = null;

  };

  $scope.rowClick = function(car){
      $scope.make= car.make;
      $scope.model= car.model;
  };

  $scope.alert = function(){
      alert('Already exists in table');

  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for duplicates by checking each `car` in your array (comparing the make and model) - you can accomplish this with `Array.some` (returns a boolean if any of the elements in the array match the condition):

In your `add` function:

```
var hasDuplicates = $scope.cars.some(car => car.make == $scope.make && car.model == $scope.model);

if (hasDuplicates) {
    alert("Car already exists");
} else {
    $scope.cars.push({
       make: $scope.make,
       model: $scope.model
    });
}
```

If you can't use arrow syntax:

```
var hasDuplicates = $scope.cars.some(function(car) {
    return car.make == $scope.make && car.model == $scope.model;
});
```

Comment: Wow, amazing how fast that was answered. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Hey Tyme, how would I set it up without the arrow syntax. I cant get the part of your code with it working? My table wont populate.

Comment: @Mr.Mike - The second part of the answer shows how to do it without arrow syntax.

Comment: When I use the second part of the answer - I populate make and model, then click Add. Nothing passes through to the table. I have tried to add $scope.cars.push but maybe I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.add = function () {
    let dataToAdd = {
       make: $scope.make,
       model: $scope.model

    };
    let alreadyAdded = $scope.cars.some((o) => angular.equals(o, dataToAdd ));
    if (alreadyAdded) {
        $scope.alert();
        return false;
    }
    $scope.cars.push(dataToAdd);

    $scope.make = null;
    $scope.model = null;

  };
```